# Sharing Eloquent Migrations with Team

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration, database-migration

I am working with a couple of team members on a suite of web apps for our company. We have two projects that need to share a database. One project is public-facing, the other is for internal use only. We feel there has to be a better way to effectively share migrations. The apps are far too different to be separate branches of the same project. We have become frustrated with needing to compare Schema build information for simple database refreshes on our development server. There must be a better way. Please help!

If needed, I will elaborate the reasons we choose to keep these projects separate and why we are sharing a database.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the migrations a shared resource between the two projects using a third rep. When you go to migrate specify the path:

```
php artisan migrate --path=/my/other/migrations
```

Everybody sees all the tables anyway from both projects since it is a shared DB. The migrations might as well contain all the updates for both projects when run on either project, as the are already symbiotically linked.

You'd have just a small amount of technical debt if you want to decouple the projects, to remove the irrelevant tables from either build. But there's no point in taking on that debt at every merge now imo.